# Why does not conda work? Python, jupyter, anaconda navigator, etc. work fine

Tags: anaconda, conda

Every time I try to use conda to install a package I get an "Unexpected error has occurred" message.  Python, anaconda navigator, etc. work, PATH seems OK: relevant anaconda folders are there. What could be the problem?

Comment: Hello! I think this question would be more relevent [here](https://superuser.com/). people over there might be better placed to answer

Comment: Please include the exact command you ran and the full error message output. Also, it's often helpful to include the things that could be pertinent (e.g., `conda info`, conda-related sections of `.bash_profile`) even if they don't seem off to you.